# What is the meaning of the prefix 'Speculative' and 'Checked' of Turbofan operators?

Tags: javascript, v8, jit

In the Turbofan IR, there are several operators whose name begins with 'Speculative' or 'Checked' (e.g. SpeculativeSafeIntegerAdd, CheckedInt32Add, CheckedFloat64ToInt32, ...).

What is the meaning of those prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SpeculativeSafeIntegerAdd" means "type feedback suggests that this `+` adds small integers, but that assumption must be guarded with a type check". It's an intermediate-level node that will be lowered further eventually.

"CheckedInt32Add" performs an int32 addition, checks for overflow, and does a deopt on overflow.

For other operations, the meaning of the prefixes will be similar.

When in doubt, read the source to see when/how these operands are created, and how they are used/lowered later. (That's what I do to answer questions like this.)

Comment: Hi, I have a question about 'but that assumption must be guarded with a type check' part - does it imply that if type mismatches it must be undefined behavior, or it means that SpeculativeSafeIntegerAdd raises deopt?

Comment: I am wondering about this because I saw some TurboFan IRs feeding Parameter node into SpeculativeNumberXX op without any guard, but Parameter could be any type other than Number. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Failing guard checks cause deopts. Making assumptions about the types of parameters is one of the classic cases that require checks. I'm sure there will be a check if you follow the evolution of the graph far enough.

Comment: I think my observation was correct because the graph was pretty small - it looked like this https://postimg.cc/v4GgF4WH . Also, it seems lowering SpeculativeSafeIntegerAdd contains CheckedFloat64ToInt32 which has the prefix 'Checked' (https://postimg.cc/YhKLRn0F ) - probably Speculative itself also does deopt as well.